# Best practice for handling constants in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With React Hooks, what is the best practice for storing a constant that requires significant computation to initialize but then doesn't change across re-renders?

#### Option 1: Constant Outside of Hook Definition

```
const x = heavyCalculation();
export default function MyHook() {
  return <div>x</div>
}
```

#### Option 2: useMemo

```
export default function MyHook() {
  const x = useMemo(() => heavyCalculation(), [])
  return <div>x</div>
}
```

#### Option 3: useRef

```
export default function MyHook() {
  const x = useRef(heavyCalculation())
  return <div>x</div>
}
```

I like Option 1, but I don't know if it's considered the best for hooks stylistically.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is meant for such discussions, on stackoverflow they are considered offtopic.

Comment: @Deykun please look at the CR Help center again: [_It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?"_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 *works*, but it's not particularly flexible - what if multiple instances were rendered at a given time, and they didn't all share the same `heavyCalculation` result? But if you can count on the value only having to be computed exactly once, across all components, go for it.

Option 2 is the right choice, but note that you can simplify it to:

```
export default function MyHook() {
  const x = useMemo(heavyCalculation, [])
  return <div>{x}</div>
}
```

(also note that you do need `{x}`, not just `x`, to show the `x` result)

Option 3 will not work, since `heavyCalculation` will be invoked on every render. (You'd also have to reference `x.current`, not just `x`)